# How to access variable in TWIG which starts with special character

Tags: php, twig

So i have an array in PHP which looks like the one bellow:

```
array(
  'data' => array(
    '#els' => 1
  )
);
```

So to access it you would normally do `$variable['data']['#els']` which is no problem for PHP, but when i try to access it in TWIG like so `{% set els = items.content.data.#els %}` i get an error as the els variable has a pound symbol at the beggining, if i remove the pound symbol from the array, i can easily access it in twig with `items.content.data.els` but i can't do that as that pound symbol is important, so how i can access the `#els` variable in TWIG?

Comment: Does `items.content.data['#els']` work?

Comment: from the doc: You can use a dot (.) to access attributes of a variable (methods or properties of a PHP object, or items of a PHP array), or the so-called "subscript" syntax ([]):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax, as described in [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables):

```
{% set els = items.content.data['#els'] %}
```